# VBA and Reports

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I'm a little out of my depth here.

I have no idea how to create a report and pass a query or table's info into it.

I can export to excel using VBA just fine. I just don't know how to add it to a report's menu in access and am unable to find info on the web about my very specific issue.

Here's some simple code I built to make a query to export to excel.

```
Public Sub updateQuery()

If cmbAnalyst.ListIndex <> -1 Then

    whereAtt = whereAtt & " and Analyst = '" & Me.cmbAnalyst.Value & "'"
    Call queryBuilder

ElseIf cmbGrpName.ListIndex <> -1 Then

    whereAtt = whereAtt & " and GroupName = '" & Me.cmbGrpName.Value & "'"
Else

    Call Form_Load

End If

End Sub
Private Sub Form_Load()

whereAtt = "Select * from tblActionLog where LogID is not null"
cmbAnalyst.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT Analyst FROM tblActionLog"
cmbGrpName.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT GroupName FROM tblActionLog"
Call queryBuilder

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The report object has a recordsource property. You can set this to be a table or field. I'm guessing your requirements are a bit more complicated though?